# how to get connection string without opening a connection in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it possible to do this in Java? Host in the connection string is unresolvable so I am getting SQLException in getConnection() of DataSource before I am able to call getMetaData on the connection.

This is my code:

```
DataSource ds = null;
Connection connection = null;
DataSourceProbeRequest request = null;

try {
  request = (DataSourceProbeRequest) probeRequest;

  ds = request.getDataSource();

  connection = ds.getConnection();
  final boolean validConnection = connection != null && connection.isValid(5000);
  if (validConnection) {
    LOGGER.info("Connection is ok: " + request.getTargetId());
    return new ProbeResult(request.getTargetId(), buildDatasourceMsg(connection, true));
  } else {
    return new ProbeResult(request.getTargetId(), new Exception(buildDatasourceMsg(connection, false)));
  }
} catch (Exception exp) {
  return new ProbeResult(request.getTargetId(), exp);
} finally {
  if (connection != null) {
    try {
      connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      LOGGER.warn("Failed to close database connection", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Because the host is unreachable, `connection = ds.getConnection();` would throw exception and causes `new ProbeResult(request.getTargetId(), exp)` returned. However, the exception only has error message like `IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`. It doesn't give the host name in the connection string. I want to display the host name (or connection string) so that it can be diagnosed

Comment: Can you please explain little more

Comment: The connection string contains a host that can't be reached (dns resolution failure). You get SQLException in getConnection() call on DataSource. That's before you can call getMetaData() on the prior connection in order to get the connection string to help you see the host name. Am I making sense?

Comment: The underlying driver is oracle and using oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource

Comment: If 'host in the connection string' is part of an error message, you should clearly say so. In fact you should post the exception and its stack trace. If not, it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a stupid error message from Oracle. Network adapters don't establish connections. TCP does. And, as you say, it suppresses all the important information.

But have a look further down the call stack, by chasing the `detail` chain from the original exception. Somewhere there should be a `ConnectException` with the message you want.

Comment: Thank you. It solves my problem. I has to use the message exp.getCause().getCause() to get the real message